# delete first row of multiple csv in a folder windows command line

Tags: csv, command-line

I have multiple csv files in a folder.

I want to delete the first row of each csv in the folder using windows command line.

I am not familiar with windows command line so I will need information regarding how to call the folder within the console.

I do not want to make new files with the "subtracted" row, I just want to replace the original file or overwrite it.

Comment: If possible, install git bash and run linux commands (sed -i '' 1d file.csv)

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a reasonable solution, but I cannot install git bash on this machine without IT approval. Do you know how to do it in windows command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Powershell

```
Get-ChildItem "path\to\your\directory" -Filter *.csv | 
Foreach-Object {
    $import = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $import | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to make sense. Can you please provide guidance to accessing all of the csvs in a folder and executing this without creating a new file? I understand that path\to\file.csv is representing the location of the folder, but when I use C:\Users\Downloads for example I get an error of unauthorized access. Does the file.csv mean look at all the csv files in the folder? Does the second like with file2.csv create a new file? I do not want it to make a new file.

Comment: Improvised the answer